# How to include mySQL server into an installation program

Tags: java, mysql, installation

I just finished a java application that uses MySQL. I want to distribute my application and I have a problem:
**how can I create an .exe installer that will both install my application AND install my SQL server (with a specific password)?**
I managed to create an exe file for my application and the installer but I don't know how to add a MySQL server with it (I don't want users to install MySQL server themselves with all the complicated steps).

Any info would be welcome :)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a database like H2? Ibstalling MySQL Server on client devices doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: I'll look into h2. May i know why it wouldn't be wise to install MySQL Server on clients device?

Comment: Your installer has to check if there's already an instance of MySQL on the client device before you install your version.  I've used [NSIS: Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) in the past to install software on Windows systems.